# Get ID of row from max value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new in database

I have the following table:

```
id  group       factor
------------------------
1   11          1
2   11          5
4   11          2
5   12          3
6   12          2
7   13          4
8   13          1
9   13          8
10  14          6
```

I need to get the id of the one that has the largest factor based on its group, for example, in the case of group 11, the row with the largest factor is 5, so I need to obtain the id of that row, in this case 2.

please if someone can show me the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(group) group factor, id
FROM tab
ORDER BY group, factor DESC;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=85233dad4d6236896d7787520200a070)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple CTE (Common Table Expression) for it, as in:

```
with
x as (
  select group_id, max(factor) as max_factor from my_table group by group_id
)
select t.*
from my_table t
join x on x.group_id = t.group_id and x.max_factor = t.factor
```

This solution has the [desirable?] feature that in case there are multiple rows tied in first place in the same group, it will show them all, not just one [randomly] of them.

Comment: It works correctly, but as when the exercise gets complicated, I have some problems. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you know the group in advance, e.g. 11, then you can simply do:

```
SELECT id
FROM tab
WHERE group = 11
ORDER BY factor DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Otherwise if you want the result for each group that exists in the table then Lukasz Szozda's answer it the way to go.